# Crop an image based on one channel with ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick

I have an image (see below) with a border in the red channel and the stuff I'd like to keep in the green channel.

I'd like to:

- crop the image to the extent of the red pixels (ignoring any which aren't 100% red)
- crop N more pixels (4, say) from each side
- delete the red channel
- copy the green channel to the red and blue channels (making it white)
- save the result into a new file

I've been reading the docs but am stumped, can anyone with more experience of this program help me?

I'm using windows, version: ImageMagick 7.1.0-7 Q16-HDRI x64 2021-09-12

Thanks,
Charlie

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```
magick l1AvD.png -trim -shave 10 -channel g -separate result.png
```

It does the following steps:

- trim to any/all channels
- remove 10 pixels off all sides
- extracts just the green channel and saves as a single-channel, greyscale image

You may want to add `-threshold 50%` after `-separate` if you want pure blacks and whites. You may want to add `+repage` after `-separate` to make it forget where on the canvas it originally came from.

[image]

Comment: It's a bit more tricky than that, the red might not be a regular rectange, and I need to trim to the fully red pixels where the channel is 100%. I got an answer elsewhere, see below

Answer (score 0):

The [answer](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/discussions/4243#discussioncomment-1348690) came from the GitHub discussions page, this seems to work:

```
magick ^
  file.png ^
  -strip ^
  ( +clone ^
    -color-threshold "red-red" ^
    -set option:MYCROP "%%@" ^
    +delete ^
  ) ^
  -crop %%[MYCROP] +repage ^
  -shave 4x4 +repage ^
  -channel G -separate +channel ^
  output.png
```